# String.substring vs String[].split

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

I have a comma delaminated string that when calling `String.split(",")` it returns an array size of about 60. In a specific use case I only need to get the value of the second value that would be returned from the array. So for example `"Q,BAC,233,sdf,sdf,"` all I want is the value of the string after the first `','` and before the second `','`. The question I have for performance am I better off parsing it myself using substring or using the split method and then get the second value in the array? Any input would be appreciated. This method will get called hundreds of times a second so it's important I understand the best approach regarding performance and memory allocation.

-Duncan

Comment: Profile it. Period.

Comment: The problem with my profiler is that I don't know where all the char[] arrays I see in the profiler come from. What is the use case to profile this and get metrics?

Comment: I didn't mean profile the number of char arrays created. Profile the time it takes to execute a somewhat realistic benchmark, before and after the "optimization", to see if it makes any noticeable difference.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since `String.Split` returns a `string[]`, using a 60-way `Split` would result in about sixty needless allocations per line. `Split` goes through your entire string, and creates sixty new object plus the array object itself. Of these sixty one objects you keep exactly one, and let garbage collector deal with the remaining sixty.

If you are calling this in a tight loop, a substring would definitely be more efficient: it goes through the portion of your string up to the second comma `,`, and then creates one new object that you keep.

```
String s = "quick,brown,fox,jumps,over,the,lazy,dog";
int from = s.indexOf(',');
int to = s.indexOf(',', from+1);
String brown = s.substring(from+1, to);
```

The above [prints](http://ideone.com/ku21ya) `brown`

When you run this multiple times, the `substring` wins on time hands down: 1,000,000 iterations of `split` take 3.36s, while 1,000,000 iterations of `substring` take only 0.05s. And that's with only eight components in the string! The difference for sixty components would be even more drastic.

Comment: That is, of course, assuming it's actually performance critical and you couldn't achieve more speed up in other ways. Programmers have a tendency to make wildly inaccurate guesses about that.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers. Seems like the theme is substring and you explained it the best.

Comment: I wrote a method to retrieve a token at a desired index, http://pastebin.com/R9Z6uW6H

Answer (score 4):

ofcourse why iterate through whole string, just use `substring()` and `indexOf()`

Comment: The possibility of off-by-one errors? The increased amount of less obvious code?

Answer (score 3):

You are certainly better off doing it by hand for two reasons:

- `.split()` takes a string as an argument, but this string is interpreted as a `Pattern`, and for your use case `Pattern` is costly;
- as you say, you only need the second element: the algorithm to grab that second element is simple enough to do by hand.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like:

```
final int first = searchString.indexOf(",");
final int second = searchString.indexOf(",", first+1);
String result= searchString.substring(first+1, second);
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the purpose of declaring the index values as final?

Comment: It's just a code convention I am used to. I make all variables **final** which are only assigned once.

Comment: Thank I you upvoted! Please upvote my question I want to break 600!

Answer (score 1):

My first inclination would be to find the index of the first and second commas and take the substring.

The only real way to tell for sure, though, is to test each in your particular scenario. Break out the appropriate stopwatch and measure the two.