# When to use: Substring or Split using delimiter? Which is better?

Tags: java, split, comparison, substring, delimiter

In my recent experience I have used both split using delimiter, and substring functions. Just wondering if anyone can put some light on which one is better, and in what conditions?

**EDIT:**

My main concern is the effect of these functions on performance and code quality. (If I could use any of these, which one should be preferred? and if any other deciding factors, please mention.)

*On a side note, had this discussion with a co-worker who said he isn't comfortable using substring. That's what got me thinking..*

Just for information, I have a long ID that contains a URL, and two different IDs that I need to get and store separately. The URL is the same in all, IDs are of same length in each, and thus length and indexes are going to be constant, so I know the exact index location, and I also have characters like  **#**  between the IDs which I can use as delimiter. The ID looks something like:

```
http://xyz.com#12345#ASDFG
```

So, I had a choice. I used split using delimiter **#**, but wanted to know what would have been a better choice.

Comment: Possible duplicate.-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997361/string-substring-vs-string-split

Comment: But they're completely diferent functions. One can't be better than another, because they do the different things.

Comment: @LeonardoPugliese, I understand they are different. I was just wondering which one is better if we had to choose.

Comment: @chrylis I don't understand why the question has been closed as unclear. I provided all the information I had, and explained my concern..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing like which is better. Both are equally good, but it majorly depends on the scenario where you using it.

When you know the index use `substring`.

`split()` internally creates `Pattern.compile` which is an expensive operation. Also `.split()` takes a string as an argument, but this string is interpreted as a Pattern

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what the correct tool for the job is and weather or not you can predetermine where to split the string!

`Split` is going to create an array of strings, each element containing the values between the characters you chose to delimit by.

`Substring` is going to return you a partial string value depending on which index you provide.

As for applicable scenario's check out a [great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997361/string-substring-vs-string-split) provided by dasblinkenlight.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the indexes then it is better to use `subString()`,Since `spilt()` creates an array of Strings